# Facebook Sharing Debugger gives the wrong result in spite of correct og:image

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, meta-tags

I was trying to share something on my Facebook and I noticed Facebook crawler cannot get the og:image correctly.

https://singlebeep.com/

When you check the Scraped URL you can also see the information does not match the stuff that's being shared by Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsinglebeep.com

Also it appears that the behaviors of http and https are different. What I do for http is redirect it to https with cloudfront. But somehow the results are different.

Comment: You have `https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOloQ.jpg` set as og:image. Those free image hosters often have "hotlink protection" mechanisms at work, and that can easily lead to problems when the FB scraper tries to request the image. Host your image somewhere else.

Comment: I see. lemme see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do not omit the protocol in the og tags, add http or https to `og:url` and `og:image` and scrape it again.

Comment: I just added https to og:url but it's still showing the same thing. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsinglebeep.com

Comment: does not look like it, i still don´t see it in the source

Comment: Weird. When I click on Scraped URL I can see the tag `<meta property="og:url" content="https://singlebeep.com">` is there.

Answer (score 0):

I setup my static website on S3 and have Cloudfront to redirect requests to this websote. It appears that Cloudfront causes the 404 there for some reason. But when I try to crawl using the FB debugger using the following link

http://singlebeep.com?q=123

and it works.